# while creating dlls using cygwin

Tags: c++, c, gcc, cygwin

Can anyone help with this? I need to compile files to create a dll and was told to use cygwin, which I have not used before.

I am getting an error while searching for c compiler.

```
"checking build system type... i686-pc-cygwin
checking host system type... i686-pc-cygwin
checking for gcc... i686-pc-mingw32-gcc
checking whether the C compiler works... no
configure: error: in `/home/acer/sqlcipher-master':
configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables
See `config.log' for more details
"
```

Comment: Get a compiler.  Install `gcc`.

Comment: BTW, questions for system configuration will probably be better addressed over on SuperUser.com (another StackExchange site).  StackOverflow is for the programming questions that arise once you're actually working on code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like the development packages weren't installed when you installed Cygwin (or at least, not fully or correctly installed).  The Cygwin installer is rather non-intuitive, to say the least, so I'm not surprised.  The Cygwin web page notes: "When installing packages for the first time, setup*.exe does not install every package. Only the minimal base packages from the Cygwin distribution are installed by default."

Go back and re-run your Cygwin installer.  When you get to the page with the list of categories of packages, look for the "Devel" category.  You'll probably want the gcc and the mingw32 packages, as I believe that mingw32 is used for Windows compatibility and you're trying to build a DLL.

I've not actually built any DLLs under Cygwin, so this is as far as I can take you.  Good luck!